# What is the best supported microSD card's with it class for Raspberry Pi2 Model B?

Tags: pi-2, pi-models

I'm currently running with class 4, 4GB card. 
I thinking to upgrade.

Comment: Class 10 is recommended, size depends on your usage.. If you use a lot of videos and stuff, you might be better of with a bigger one.

Comment: This question is, at best, marginally related to the Pi. There is an awful lot of BS written about this. The Class rating is the minimum sequential sustainable write rate. Most Pi activity is read/write on small files. There are probably differences between SD cards, but these are unrelated to Class.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I am putting this on hold as a question what is *best* is really opinion-based. Check the already linked resource http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards for supported cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a Class 10 SD card as recommended on [SD cards - Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sd-cards.md).

Also, [RPi SD cards - eLinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) was helpful for checking reliable brands.

So, I got a 16GB Samsung EVO, but you can choose the brand and capacity you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" Micro SD card. It all boils down to pure performance, compatibility, and your needs and purposes. If I were to decide what is the "best" card, it would be a [Samsung Micro SD PRO+ 128GB](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage-accessories/MB-MD128DA/AM). Ridiculous, isn't it?

Some cards perform best with small operations, others with large operations, and others are best for continuous data streams. Like I've said, it depends on your needs.

Start reading the fine print at the back of the packaging.